# How to connect to an UltraVNC server with private IP address?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, vnc, ultravnc

I have an UltraVNC server setup on my computer. my computer is behind either a proxy or a NAT server. and he has a private IP address.

is it possible to configure it in such a way that the UltraVNC server is accessible from the internet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all lightly hood you are behind a NAT'ed firewall/router. In that case you have to use [port forwarding](http://portforward.com/help/portforwarding.htm) in your router/firewall.

[Read more on UltraVnc's site](http://www.uvnc.com/addons/routerconf.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. this is exactly what i was afraid of : port forwarding. to do that, i need to have access to the router/firewall. but I don't have access. is there any other way ?

Comment: @attilah - I don't think you can with VNC. I have used Logmein free for a few years and like it better than VNC. It traverses your NAT by connecting to servers owned by Logemein. https://secure.logmein.com/